# Prevent duplicate increment values during parallel transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions, auto-increment

I use transactions in MySQL to store orders. Each order has `OrderID (BIGINT)`, which looks like this: XXXXXX0001, with last four digits incrementing (1620200001, 1620200002, 1620200003, ...).

The transaction works as follows:

```
start transaction
get new OrderID (increment by 1)
do some stuff
commit/rollback
```

Saving the transaction can take up to several seconds and if multiple orders are created in very short timespan, duplicate `OrderID`'s can be inserted into database. Before first order is commited, second is assigned the same `OrderID`, which, at the moment is next in line.

What is best way to prevent this? Having `UNIQUE OrderID` does not solve it (there would be rollback in second order). I could get rid of transaction and save `OrderID` quicker, but this leads to other potential problems and does not entirely solve this (just reduces chances of problem happening).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Search for it in the manual on [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html). It's a long page, but AUTO_INCREMENT is documented about 1/4 of the way down the page.

Briefly, you just declare the primary key with a column option:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...other columns... 
);
```

The initial value is 1, or you can make it start at a higher value:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=1620200001;
```

A table with an auto-increment column ensures that each concurrent transaction gets a unique, increasing value. There is no race condition, because the INSERT acquires a brief table-lock during which it increments the value. Unlike transaction-based locks, the auto-increment table lock is released immediately. So concurrent sessions don't have to wait for your transaction to finish.

Auto-increment is guaranteed to be unique. That is, the same value will not be allocated to multiple sessions. However, it's not guaranteed to allocate *consecutive* values. Also, it may allocate a value to one session, but that session decides to rollback its transaction. The value it had allocated is NOT returned to any kind of queue of values, because there has probably other sessions that have allocated the next few values in the meantime. So it's possible to "lose" values and then your table has "gaps" or non-consecutive values.

Do not worry about gaps. These could also happen even if the values were consecutive, because you might delete a row later.

Comment: Thank you Bill, unfortunately it seems that table can have only one AUTO_INCREMENT column (i need more, each order has unique OrderID and some have unique DocumentID, which also needs to be incremented). but your answer answers the question as I wrote it, so I accept it.

Comment: Correct, you can only have one column declared as auto-increment per table in MySQL. If you need another solution you could use PostgreSQL and create distinct sequence objects.